# Why is only the first frame rendered repeatedly when rendering my animation?

Tags: rendering, keyframes

I just started learning Blender today and I've encountered as an issue with rendering. When I set up my scene (which involves a cloth falling onto a sphere) and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to render my animation, only the first frame is rendered repeatedly, even though Blender is clearly iterating through every frame (the frame counter is going up).

On top of this, if I try to render one frame (which is not the first) specifically with <kbd>F2</kbd>, the first frame is rendered instead. The object to be rendered is snapped out of the camera view to the origin when rendering as well.

I am using Blender 2.83.2. Any suggestions on how to solve the issue? Perhaps I'm using the software incorrectly?

In terms of settings, I have not done any customization and I simply render my scene as-is.

Comment: Have you added a key frame at the start and end as well? (I used to forget doing this when I was a beginner)

Comment: To be completely honest, I don't know how to do this. Is it the insert keyframe button? If so, there seem to be a ton of options (location, etc...).

Comment: So I figured out keyframes but the problem is still occuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by the physic simulation that is not cached / baked.

Go to "Physics Properties" tab, then *Cache*, then *Delete all Bakes* and then *Bake all dynamics*. This should be enough.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The render works as expected now. :)